# Making Bootstrap header NOT fixed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to make my bootstrap header NOT fixed. I want it to stay at the top of the actual page and not the browser window as a fixed header is.

In other words I want the header to scroll with the rest of the page contents.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't make sense, can you provide us a reproducible example of your issue in a [jsffidle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the class `navbar-fixed-top` from your `navbar`.

Then, you can either use bootstrap's `navbar-default` class, and `navbar-static-top` to have the exact same `navbar`, but static.

There are some examples included with Bootstrap 3.0, you can find them under `examples` folder.